# Javascript - Why can't I update the textContent of an h3 with my conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I have a conditional that checks to see if an item has been added to an array. If that item has been added to the array, I set a previously declared variable "isDouble" from 'false' to 'true'. I then later use another conditional to check if 'isDouble' is true.

If the 'isDouble' is 'false', I want to create a brand new h3 and populate the text with the quantity of that item - if not, I simply want to update the quantity of that item WITHOUT creating a new h3.

The function that is handling all this is called 'addCartItem()' - nearer the end of the code

Can someone please help?

Thank you

> JAVASCRIPT

```
(function () {

    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    let totalBasket = document.querySelector('.totalBasket');
    let cartCount = document.querySelector('.cartCount');
    let cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector('.cartItems');


    function DrinkBluePrint(name, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = 0;
    }

    let latte = new DrinkBluePrint('Latte', 5.00);
    let flatW = new DrinkBluePrint('Flat White', 3.60);
    let cap = new DrinkBluePrint('Cap', 2.75);
    let moc = new DrinkBluePrint('Moc', 3.15);
    let cortado = new DrinkBluePrint('Cortado', 3.15);


    let array = [
   latte,
    flatW,
    cap,
    moc,
    cortado
];


    let cart = [];
    let p;
    let button;
    let isDouble = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        p = document.createElement('p');
        button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = 'Add';
        let text = document.createTextNode(array[i].name);
        p.appendChild(text);
        body.appendChild(p);
        body.appendChild(button);


        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (cart.indexOf(array[i]) !== -1) {
                isDouble = true;
            }
            cart.push(array[i]);
            displayTotal();
            addCartItem();
        });

        function displayTotal() {
            let total = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                total += cart[i].price;
            }
            totalBasket.textContent = '£ ' + total.toFixed(2);
            cartCount.textContent = `You have ${cart.length} items in your cart`;
            if (total >= 10) {
                let discountedPrice = (total - 3);
                totalBasket.textContent = '£ ' + discountedPrice.toFixed(2);
            }
        }

        // code that needs fixed below 

        function addCartItem() {

            // add one to quantity
            addOne();

            // create h3 and append text node
            let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
            let h3Text = document.createTextNode(array[i].name + " " + array[i].price.toFixed(2) + " x " + array[i].quantity);
            h3.appendChild(h3Text);

            // check to see if item has already been added to cart
            if (!isDouble) {
                // if item hasn't been added before, append the h3 to the div
                cartItemsDiv.appendChild(h3);
            } else {
                // if item has already been added, then update the text of the existing h3
                h3.textContent = array[i].name + " " + array[i].price.toFixed(2) + " x " + array[i].quantity + " blah blah blah";
            }

            console.log(h3.textContent);

        }

        function addOne() {
            let itemQuantity = array[i].quantity += 1;
        }





    };


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you perform:

```
        // create h3 and append text node
        let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
        let h3Text = document.createTextNode(array[i].name + " " + array[i].price.toFixed(2) + " x " + array[i].quantity);
        h3.appendChild(h3Text);

        if (!isDouble) {
            // if item hasn't been added before, append the h3 to the div
            cartItemsDiv.appendChild(h3);
        } else {
            // if item has already been added, then update the text of the existing h3
            h3.textContent = array[i].name + " " + array[i].price.toFixed(2) + " x " + array[i].quantity + " blah blah blah";
        }
```

In the consequent block of your `if` clause, where `isDouble` is false (`!isDouble == true`), you appear to do what you want. However, in the alternative block, you do not modify the *existing* `h3` element, you modify the `h3` element you *just* created in the `addCartItem` function. You need to select the existing `h3` element in the alternative block.

You could give the `h3` element an id, based upon `array[i].name`, and then when adjusting an `h3` already on the page, query for the element with that id, and then modify it.

```
let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
h3.id = array[i].name;
...
else {
    h3 = document.getElementById(array[i].name);
    ... // modify the h3 created earlier
}
```

Comment: Hey, David, thanks! I put that code in, however, when I click on a different button to add a new item, the cart total goes up, but the name of the newly added item doesn't appear. The first item I add and its quantity goes up, though.

Comment: Ok, I can now click and add each new item to the DOM, but only if I click on the item button once. If I click on latte twice, for example, I can't add the other items

Answer (score 0):

**You can not change data using textcontent.**

let h3 = document.createElement('h3');

if (!isDouble) {

let h3Text = document.createTextNode(array[i].name + " " + array[i].price.toFixed(2) + " x " + array[i].quantity);

h3.appendChild(h3Text);

cartItemsDiv.appendChild(h3);

} else {

h3.textContent = array[i].name + " " + array[i].price.toFixed(2) + " x " + array[i].quantity + " blah blah blah";

h3.appendChild(h3Text);

}

Comment: What do you mean by "*you can not change data*"? Of course one can modify the DOM by assigning to `.textContent`.

Comment: Please [format the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in your answer and describe what you changed and how it works.